# Is there a spherical coordinates system for vectors of complex numbers?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, spherical-coordinates

Suppose I have a scalar field $f(\vec{x})$, where $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}_3$, and I wish to average $f$ over a sphere $|\vec{x}|=R$:

$\displaystyle\langle f\rangle_{R} = \frac{\int_{S} f(\vec{x})\, dS}{\int_{S}\, dS} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=\pi}\int_{\phi=0}^{\phi=2\pi} f(\vec{x})\, \sin(\theta)\, d\phi\,d\theta $

where $\phi$ is the azimuth. This is relatively straight-forward for $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}_3$.

However, if my vector elements are now complex, $\vec{z}\in\mathbb{C}_3$, is there an equivalent spherical transform? That is, while I can define:

$\begin{align*}
z_1 = & r \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)\\
z_2 = & r \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\\
z_3 = & r \cos(\theta)
\end{align*}$

where $z_1,z_2,z_3,r,\theta,\phi\in\mathbb{C}$, does the surface element $dS = r^2 \sin(\theta)\, d\theta\, d\phi$ still hold for an integral over the complex sphere $\vec{z}^{\ast}\cdot \vec{z}=R^2$? What would my limits of integration be, given that $\theta,\phi\in\mathbb{C}$?

I am open to any suggestions. Ultimately, I would like to average a real-valued scalar field $f(\vec{z})$ over a complex sphere of $\vec{z}^{\ast}\cdot \vec{z}=R^2$.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just identify $\mathbb{C}^3$ with $\mathbb{R}^6$ and use the spherical coordinates there?

Comment: NB if you think just of a complex circle as a 3-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ you can see that $w^2+z^2=c^2$  is not compact - think of the intersection of this "circle" with the copy of $\mathbb{R}^2$ determined by $\Re z = 0 = \Im w$

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks! I did not think of that, that is what I will do.

Comment: @DavidHolden, thank you for your comment, but I am not quite sure what you mean? After some thought, a complex circle in $\mathbb{C}^2$ should satisfy the equation $\Re(z_1)^2+\Im(z_1)^2+\Re(z_2)^2+\Im(z_2)^2=R^2$. Is this not equivalent to a hypersphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: yes, sorry, my mistake. i was thinking of an algebraically defined ideal in $\mathbb{C}[w,z]$ instead of an object described by metric geometry

Comment: No problem. Thanks!